# Detect presence of objects using OpenCV in live iphone camera

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

Can anyone help me to detect realtime objects in iPhone camera using OpenCV?

My actual objective is to give an alert to users while an object interfering on a specific location of my application camera view.

My current thinking is to capture an image with respect to my camera overlay view which represents a specific location of my camera view. And then I process that image using OpenCV to detect objects by colors. If there I can identify an object in a specific image. I will give an alert to user in camera overlay itself. I coudn't know how I can detect an object from UIImage.

Please direct me if anyone knows some other good way to achieve my goal. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I solved my issue by the following way,

1. Created an image capture module with AVFoundation classes (AVCaptureSession)
2. Capturing simultaneous image buffer through a timer working along with camera module.
3. Processing captured frames to find objects through OpenCV
   (Cropping, grayscale, threshold, feature detection etc...)
   Referral Link: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html
4. Alerting user through animated camera overlay view

Anyway the detection of objects through image processing is not much accurate. We need to have a object sensor (like a depth sensor in Kinet camera or similar) to detect objects in real scenario in live streaming, or may be we have to create AI for it perfect working.